# How to fix, MVC model null issue if int is pass as null from json

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am using [formio](https://formio.github.io/formio.js/app/builder) to produce forms from json in my asp.net core mvc web application. My model definition is given below.

```
public class MyRootModel
    {
        public Data data { get; set; }

        public class Data
        {
            public Client client { get; set; }
            public Contact contact { get; set; }
        }
    }
public class Client
    {
        public string Forename { get; set; }
        public string Surname { get; set; }
        public int? Gender { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateofBirth { get; set; }
    }
public class Contact
    {
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string Street { get; set; }
        public string Street2 { get; set; }

    }
```

The post method on my controller is given below.

```
[HttpPost]
        public MyResponse Next([FromBody] MyRootModel formCollection)
        {            
            MyResponse myResponse = new MyResponse ();
            myResponse.ReturnType = "Success";
            myResponse.ReturnMessage = "Well done";
            return myResponse ;
        }
```

The Gender on the form is a html5 select type. When the form is submitted, formCollection object on my controller is initialised automatically as json is passed from the client side. However, if user does not select any value in the Gender drop down, then the formCollection is appearing as null. I have looked at the json being passed and noticed that `"gender": "null"` is passed and this is the reason formCollection is appearing null. Even though I have defined Gender as int? in my client model.

I am displaying json submitted from the form below for both scenarios. The first scenario works fine when user selects Gender.

**formCollection is initialised properly**

```
{
  "data": {
    "client": {
      "forename": "abc",
      "surname": "def",
      "gender": 2
    },
    "contact": {
      "city": "ghi",
      "street": "jkl"
    },
    "submit": true
  },
  "metadata": {}
}
```

**formColletion is becoming null when following json is passed**

```
{
  "data": {
    "client": {
      "forename": "dsfaasdf",
      "surname": "asdf",
      "gender": "null"
    },
    "contact": {
      "city": "asdf",
      "street": ""
    },
    "submit": true
  },
  "metadata": {}
}
```

I thought that `int?` allows null so I changed the Gender type from `int` to `int?` but still not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{
  "data": {
    "client": {
      "forename": "dsfaasdf",
      "surname": "asdf",
      "gender": null 
    },
    "contact": {
      "city": "asdf",
      "street": ""
    },
    "submit": true
  },
  "metadata": {}
}
```

Try passing the gender as null instead of "null".This is beacause the gender propert in the model class Client in your code ,is in int but you are trying to pass a string.

Comment: I don't know if I can change the json as it is produced by formio on submit.

Comment: Your direction was correct, I found that I can use hooks as per formio documentation to change values before submission. I am using following hook {
        hooks: {
            beforeSubmit: (submission, next) => {                                
                if (submission.data.client.gender == null || submission.data.client.gender == "")
                    submission.data.client.gender = null;               
                // Only call next when we are ready.
                next();
            }
        }
    }